# Python3 return multiple contextmanagers from a function to be used in a single with statement

Tags: python, psycopg2

Given:

```
con = psycopg2.connect()

with con, con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # some query inside here
```

According to the psycopg2 documentation https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control, the con object manages the transaction and takes care of commit and rollback of the db transaction. So both the `con` and `con.cursor()` are required in the `with` statement to properly manage commit/rollback

Now I want repeat the `with` part of the code multiple times, to do multiple transactions, such as

```
con = psycopg2.connect()

with con, con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # some query inside here

with con, con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # another query inside here

...

with con, con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # final query inside here
```

This works but this requires me to copy paste the `con, con.cursor()` part of the `with` statement for every `with` block.

Now I was wondering if it is possible in python to create a function that returns something that I can pass directly to the `with` statement to reduce `con, con.cursor()` to `some_custom_function()`

Something along these lines:

```
con = psycopg2.connect()

def cursor():
  return con, con.cursor() # this doesn't work

with cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # some query inside here

with cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # another query inside here

...

with cursor() as c:
  c.execute() # final query inside here
```

(You may be wondering why, but the `con.cursor()` method also takes arguments such as `cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor`. Then I would have to repeat those arguments with every `with` statement as well. But for simplicity of this example, I've left that out of the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(...)


@contextmanager
def with_txn_and_cursor():
    with con, con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as cur:
        yield cur


with with_txn_and_cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(...)
```

If you need both the `con` and `cur`, yield a tuple out of the context manager.

```
@contextmanager
def with_txn_and_cursor_2():
    with con, con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) as cur:
        yield (con, cur)


with with_txn_and_cursor_2() as (con, cur):
    cur.execute(...)
```